# Decode php encoded json not working

Tags: php, json, decode

Here is my data.php

```
$global = $pdo->query("SELECT name, age");
$global = $global->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$arr = array('data'=>$global);    
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Here is my index.php

```
<html>
    <?php
        $json_url = "data.php";
        $json = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($json_url));
        $data = json_decode($json, false);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
    ?>
</html>
```

I get blank data.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide your json from $json_url?

Comment: check in data.php that $arr is not empty

Comment: how is `$pdo` initialized? And your select query appears to be missing `FROM tablename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
$global= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$arr = array('data'=>$global);    
echo json_encode($arr);
//echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure file_get_contents is actually returning something.
If not, check your logs to see what file its actually requesting. Use a full-path ex: http://location/path/to/data.php

I have had issues with reading JSON without setting the Content-Type. 
`header('Content-Type: application/json')`